# mySQL Stored Procedure : input paramrter passed to the show procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

When  I tested this script in the console, it is working.

My script:

```
show fields from testdata1970_05.loadlv_test where FIELD not like 'ID_test';
```

My stored Procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `testdata1970_05`.`list_testparameters` $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `list_testparameters`(IN nametest varchar(24))
BEGIN
show fields from nametest where FIELD not like 'ID_test';
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

However when I build the stored procedure based on this script, it does not work.

Executing stored procedure:

```
call list_testparameters(loadlv_test);
```

Error:

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'loadlv_test' in 'field list'
```

Please advise why it is not working when this acript can work in the console?

Comment: Shouldn't you call it with `call list_testparameters(testdata1970_05.loadlv_test);`?

Comment: It does not work. Without upper comma, error = unknown table. And upper comma, error = Data too long for column 'nametest' at row 1

Comment: Because you defined it as `varchar(24)`, increase it to 60 or something big.

Comment: Changed to 60, instead the error says 1146 (42S02): Table 'testdata1970_05.nametest' doesn't exist. Why does this error says 'testdata1970_05.nametest'  instead of 'testdata1970_05.loadlv_test'?

Comment: Try this after BEGIN: `SET @your_table=nametest`. And then change the `show...` line to `show fields from @your_table...`. The variable assigned through the procedure seems to be the problem, is not set properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `testdata1970_05` is a database, You need to dynamically generate the SQL and execute it.

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `testdata1970_05`.`list_testparameters` $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `list_testparameters`(IN nametest varchar(24))
BEGIN
    SET @sql_text := CONCAT('show fields from ','`testdata1970_05`.`',@nametest,'` where FIELD not like ''ID_test''';
    PREPARE sqlstmt FROM @sql_text;
    EXECUTE sqlstmt;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Isn't it possible to create this sentence directly, without generating it beforehand and then executing?

Comment: Yes possible, Since there are no arguments used in the sql. But I just wanted to be on the safe side.

Comment: OK, I see. I could not figure out what's wrong in the procedure showed by the OP. Anyway, +1 for solving it this way.

Comment: Hi Shazin and fedorqui. Thanks for your help. Shazin, There is an error that I change from @nametest to nametest. So now it works. Thanks